# Typescript dynamic type for deeply nestes json object

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

is there a way of typing and accessing a deeply nested object dynamically?
(with noImplicitAny turned on)

```
//Coming as json
const myConfig = {
  is: {
    not: ["known", "in", "advance", "and"],
    deeply : {
      nested: {
        somePropA: "24"
      },
      somePropB: 42
    }
  }
}    


type TMyConfig = typeof myConfig;
type TKeys = keyof TMyConfig | keyof TMyConfig[keyof TMyConfig]
type TIs = keyof TMyConfig;
type TNotDeeply = keyof TMyConfig[keyof TMyConfig];    


//BAD, as types get lost
const BadTryA = ({myKey, config}: {myKey: TKeys, config: TMyConfig}) => {
  return <div>
    {(config.is as any)[myKey]["nested"].somePropA} //FAILS without cast to any with TS 7053
  </div>
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <BadTryA 
        myKey="deeply"
        config={myConfig}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mayer-r70h1?file=/src/App.tsx:25-803
I also tried some recursive types as well but i just can't figure it out. Help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your sandbox link doesn't go anywhere useful; it's just a default project.  Maybe you want something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX2b1m) to be a [mre] instead?  Anyway, I don't understand what you're trying to do; the only `myKey` for which `(config.is)[myKey]["nested"].somePropA` would work is `"deeply"`, which implies [this](https://tsplay.dev/w142GW) is how to fix it.  But obviously that's not what you want, so what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, within the <BadTryA /> component, thanks to the typeof type, accessing any level of "config" with dot notation works fine. But once I introduce a prop, TS can't figure out if the access works  or can be allowed anymore. Saying "config.is.deeply" is fine, but config.is[myKey] is not. I'm just wondering there must be a better solution than my "as any" cast. Link to CSB works for me btw. Thanks

Comment: If you just want `config.is[myKey]`, then `myKey` must have type `keyof typeof config.is`.  But if you want `config.is[myKey].nested.somePropA`, then `myKey` must be just `"deeply"`.  Which of those things are you trying to do?  You don't need `as any`, you need some coherent criterion for what you're trying to access.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wengYN) but again it's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strategy pattern:

```js
import React from 'react'

//Coming as json
const myConfig = {
    is: {
        not: ["known", "in", "advance", "and"],
        deeply: {
            nested: {
                somePropA: "24"
            },
            somePropB: 42
        }
    }
}


type Config = typeof myConfig;

type Props<MyKey extends keyof Config['is']> = {
    myKey: MyKey,
    config: Config,
}

type Strategy = {
    [Key in keyof Config['is']]: (arg: Props<Key>) => JSX.Element
}

const Strategy: Strategy = {
    deeply: ({ config, myKey }) => <p> {config.is[myKey]["nested"].somePropA}</p>,
    not: ({ config, myKey }) => <ul>{config.is[myKey].map(elem => <p>{elem}</p>)}</ul>

}

const BadTryA = <MyKey extends keyof Config['is']>(props: Props<MyKey>) => Strategy[props.myKey](props)

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            <BadTryA
                myKey="deeply"
                config={myConfig}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj4yMm)

As you might have noticed, I'm using explicit generic parameter `MyKey` to infer `myKey`